# Why can't Laravel find my function but the IDE can?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `helpers.php` file in the `app` directory of my Laravel project. In this file, I have a function that checks if an item's image is in the storage file and if it isn't it replaces it with an image not found, here is the file:

```php
function productImage($path)
{
    return ($path != null) && file_exists('storage/' . $path) ? asset('storage/' . $path) : asset('img/error/img-not-found.jpg');
}
```

This is where it is called in one of my `blade.php` files:

```html
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="product">
        <a href="{{ route('shop.show', $product->slug) }}" class="linkToInfo">
            <img src="{{ productImage($product->image) }}" alt="{{ $product->name }}" class="productImg">
            <p class="productData">{{ $product->name }}</p>
            <p class="productData">{{ $product->presentPrice() }}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

When I try and load this page tho, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the function "as is" (from the global namespace), you need to add the helpers.php file path to the [`autoload.files`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) part of your composer.json file, like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
         ...
     }
     "files": [
         "app/helpers.php"
     ]
}
```

Then you should execute the [`dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) command from your terminal to update the autoloader:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I thought about adding that option to my answer as well, but not sure he wants to make this part of the global estate.  IE sort of leans toward auto-magical, and something we *sometimes* stay away from, especially if there is a moderate size team working on an app.  But, is another way to do it for sure!

Comment: This was what I forgot! Thank you!

Comment: @Watercayman Right, I figured that's what he/she was looking for since he/she was using `{{ productImage(...) }}` directly in his/her templates. You could also namespace the helper functions (still without a class) if needed. Many different ways indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either register (via alias) the class or instantiate it so that blade sees it when compiling.

**Instantiate within blade**:

```
{{ \App\Helpers::instance()->productImage($product->image) }}
```

Or, what I've done usually is to **create an alias** for your **Helper** class in **config\app.php**.  This reduces a little overhead and typing as well.

**Alias:**

```
'aliases' => [
   ....
   'Helpers' => App\Helpers::class
]
```

Then call the alias in your blade (or whatever) file.

```
\Helpers::instance()->productImage($product->image);
```

I do a lot of static functions in the Helper class so I don't need to instantiate them.  E.g. `\Helpers::productImage($product->image)`.  But the above works just as well too.

Note caps on the class :)

HTH